# Auto-mount in fstab no longer working until manually running 'sudo mount -a'

Tags: mount, samba, fstab, umount

I have 3 SMB shared drives I need to connect to for work purposes. I had Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick and had all my drives loaded into fstab to be auto-mounted. Everything worked fine for a while but just before I upgraded to 11.04 Natty, the fstab auto-mount stopped working. Unfortunately I don't know what changed I made to my machine or what update installed that made this occur.

```
/etc/fstab
{snip}
//192.168.7.3/apache_proj/ /home/brett/Desktop/apache smbfs guest,rw,iocharset=utf8,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
//192.168.7.3/apache_54321/ /home/brett/Desktop/54321 smbfs guest,rw,iocharset=utf8,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
//freenas.local/shared/ /home/brett/Desktop/shared smbfs guest,rw,iocharset=utf8,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
//lamp/www/ /home/brett/Desktop/lamp smbfs username={snip},password={snip},rw,iocharset=utf8,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

When the machine boots, I run this command to get them to mount:

```
$ sudo umount /home/brett/Desktop/54321 /home/brett/Desktop/shared /home/brett/Desktop/apache; sudo mount -a 
[sudo] password for brett: 
umount: /home/brett/Desktop/54321: not mounted
umount: /home/brett/Desktop/shared: not mounted
umount: /home/brett/Desktop/apache: not mounted
Warning: mapping 'guest' to 'guest,sec=none'
Warning: mapping 'guest' to 'guest,sec=none'
Warning: mapping 'guest' to 'guest,sec=none'
mount error: could not resolve address for lamp: No address associated with hostname
```

(I run that umount as a just-in-case).

I looked through dmesg and some error logs and couldn't see why fstab was failing on my mounts. I see that my 'lamp' directive is failing, but that's because the machine is currently down.

Answer (score 2):

If it doesn't at boot and works fine after boot, it's entirely possible that the network isn't available at the time the mount is done. Networking comes up at login these days so this seems likely.

Two solutions to fix this issue:

1. You should be able to add `_netdev` to your list of mount options. This forces the mount to wait for a network interface to come up. Win.
2. Usurp the boot stack and configure your own network card. If it's a simple ethernet connection whacking something like this in `/etc/network/interfaces` might work:

   ```
   auto lo
   iface lo inet loopback

   auto eth0
   iface eth0 inet dhcp
   ```

   It's a little messier but this is what Ubuntu used to do. And it works for me.

If in doubt try both. At once if you need to.

Comment: I read in some other forums to add "_netdev" to my fstab, but that still doesn't work. My /etc/network/interfaces also already had the lines in it that you suggested.

Comment: @Brett Argl. My bad. Those aren't the lines I was looking for. I'll find them and expand. That code just sets up the loopback (localhost) virtual adapter.

Comment: You can configure your connection to start at boot time by setting it as a "System Connection" in Network Manager. But cannot say if is early enough to make the share mounted.